# How to create a tappable custom map image in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

In my ios5-application about a shopping mall I would to add a plan of the shopping mall.If a store on the plan is tapped, some info about the store should be shown. Is the easiest way to do this just to show en UIImage and measure where the user has tapped? Or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is surely a solution.

I don't know your exact needs, but an alternative may be you may consider displaying a transparent `UIButton` above each shop. Setting properly the various `UIButton`s a single method may be enough:

```
-(IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {

    switch([sender tag]) {
        case 1 : //shop 1
                 break;
        case 2 : //shop 2
                 break;
        default: break;
    }
 }
```

Yet another solution may be use [UIPopoverController](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uipopover%20apple&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD8QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/&ei=rRVVT7zTDKnf4QSBuvjRDQ&usg=AFQjCNH-Vbju_t4tzQpNaxTacocvC7qx-w&sig2=44llf8J4c22DmRAwEJoSwQ) (for iPad only) or its iPhone version [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)